# Theorem 8.19 - Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed. - Apostol

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I can't understand how to prove the following statement:

Let $\sum a_n$ be a given series with real-valued terms and define $$p_n=\frac{|a_n|+a_n}{2}\;\;\; and \;\;\; q_n=\frac{|a_n|-a_n}{2}\;\;\; (n=1,2,...)$$

Then:

ii) If $\sum |a_n|$ converges, both $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ converge and we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n - \sum _{n=1}^\infty q_n$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To see why the two sums converge, think about the comparison test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Check that

$$\begin{align*}\bullet &p_n\,,\,q_n\ge 0\\{}\\
\bullet& |a_n|\ge p_n\;,\;\;|a_n|\ge q_n\end{align*}$$

and now comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if the series  $\displaystyle \sum_n|a_n|$ is convergent then $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n$  is also convergent and this answers the first question, morover we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k=\sum_{k=0}^np_k-\sum_{k=0}^nq_k\quad \forall n\ge0$$
and this answers the second by passing to the limit $n\to\infty$.